# Getting Data from MySQL and display objects inside object for PHP Rest-API

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I am currently trying to create a Rest-API for two MySQL-Tables.
There is a table "Course-Type" and one with "Courses". The "Courses"-Table contains a Foreign-Key for the Course-Types.

When calling the API using the SQL-Code below i will get multiple Objects with the same "Course-Type".

How can i add all items with the same Course-Type inside the same Course-Type-Object to fetch using the API?

My SQL-Code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Ausbildung, Ausbildungsart WHERE Ausbildung.ART = Ausbildungsart.ID;";
```

Currently i am getting following Output when hitting the API:

```
{
   "status":"true",
   "target":"database",
   "method":"fetch-courses",
   "courses":[
      {
         "SKILLID":"7797701-901",
         "ART":"1",
         "BESCHREIBUNG":"simple course",
         "ID":"1",
         "AUSBILDUNGSBESCHREIBUNG":"type1"
      },
      {
         "SKILLID":"7797701-902",
         "ART":"2",
         "BESCHREIBUNG":"another simple course",
         "ID":"2",
         "AUSBILDUNGSBESCHREIBUNG":"type2"
      },
      {
         "SKILLID":"7797800-401",
         "ART":"2",
         "BESCHREIBUNG":"latest simple course",
         "ID":"2",
         "AUSBILDUNGSBESCHREIBUNG":"type2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to get the following Output:

```
{
   "status":"true",
   "target":"database",
   "method":"fetch-courses",
   "courses":[
      {
         "ID":"1",
         "AUSBILDUNGSBESCHREIBUNG":"type1",
         "KURSE":[
            {
               "SKILLID":"7797701-901",
               "BESCHREIBUNG":"simple course"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "ID":"2",
         "AUSBILDUNGSBESCHREIBUNG":"type2",
         "KURSE":[
            {
               "SKILLID":"7797701-902",
               "BESCHREIBUNG":"another simple course"
            },
            {
               "SKILLID":"7797800-401",
               "BESCHREIBUNG":"latest simple course"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My Current Approach is to use a foreach-Loop like this below to assign the value to the array:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Ausbildungsart;";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $courseCategories = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


    foreach ($courseCategories as &$category) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Ausbildung WHERE Ausbildung.ART = $category['ID'];";
        $response = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($con, $query), MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        array_push($category, $response);
    }

    //$query = "SELECT * FROM Ausbildung, Ausbildungsart WHERE Ausbildung.ART = Ausbildungsart.ID;";


    
    $response["status"] = "true";
    $response["target"] = "Database";
    $response["method"] = "fetch-courses";
    $response["courses"] = $courseCategories;

    echo json_encode($response); exit;
```

Comment: You need to iterate through the result (using foreach) and build a new array with the format you want. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i tried using foreach but i was not able to assign the object to the default one. Do you may have a snippet?

Comment: Please post your attempt and the result it produces. We're glad to help you sort out specific issues you might have with your existing code, but we're not here to write it all for you which a proper answer to this question would require us to.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i've added now my code. I would say that this one should work but i am struggling almost 8 hours on this and it does not work...